# JSMpeg play video in alongside canvas

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jsmpeg

I want play video in alongside canvas. I know this task maybe stranger, but i need get access for each frame. For this im using callback function which call after rendering frame for each frame. I want manipulate this frame (add rectangle) and render him on another canvas. For now i can render only 1 frame. I know why, but i dont need to call requestAnimationFrame() in the loop and pass the arg. How i can render video in my case and call requestAnimationFrame() without arg. Please help. Im broke my head.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <canvas id="video-canvas" ></canvas>
    <canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
  </div>
</template>
<script>

import JSMpeg from 'jsmpeg-player'
export default {
  props: {

  },
  data: () => ({
    myCanvas: null,
    video: null,
    ctx: null,
  }),
  mounted() {
    this.initPlayer()
    this.myCanvas = document.getElementById("canvas")
    this.ctx = this.myCanvas.getContext("2d")
  }, 
  methods: {
    initPlayer() {
      var canvas = document.getElementById('video-canvas');
      var url = 'ws://localhost:8082/';
      var player = new JSMpeg.Player(url, {
        canvas: canvas, 
        videoBufferSize: 1024*1024*4, 
        onVideoDecode: () => {
          var image = new Image()
          var currentFrameData = player.options.canvas.toDataURL('image/webp', 0.7);
          image.src = currentFrameData
          this.ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this.myCanvas.width, this.myCanvas.height)
          requestAnimationFrame()

        }
        });
    },  
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Did you fix the issue and does it work now?

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
onVideoDecode: (decoder, time) => {
  var image = new Image()
  var currentFrameData = player.options.canvas.toDataURL('image/webp', 0.7)
  image.src = currentFrameData
  image.onload = () => {
    ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.